How to limit the request.security function to previous day's regular trading hours data?
Is there a way to only load the previous trading day's data into a variable via the request.security function?
This is the code that I have so far:
//@version=5
indicator("Regular Session M1 AAPL")
regularSessionData = request.security("NASDAQ:AAPL", "1", close, barmerge.gaps_on)
plot(regularSessionData, style = plot.style_linebr)

This plot shows me the 1 minute closing data of all the available regular trading hours of AAPL, I just need it to display the previous day's RTH 1 minute closes.
Is there a direct function modifier that filters anything but the previous day's information out? I want to prevent this function of needlessly looking at 5000 candles when I only need 390 of them.
Thanks!

You can request RTH data by setting an extended session for the requested ticker via the ticker.modify() function, but keep in mind that the received data is only applied to existing candles. That is, if you want to get 1 minute data from the extended session of the previous day on a 1-minute chart, then you need more complex logic.
What symbol and timeframe are you adding this script to?

@vgladkov This is only the start of a script. I need to use only the previous trading days data from its open until its close. No extended sessions, just regular trading hours of the previous day.

Did you try using request.security_lower_tf()? Its return all data from lower resolution corresponding to actual bar.
